# RegEx : How to exclude a words from a match list

Tags: regex

I'm new with regex and I'm having a trouble with excluding a word from a list

The RegEx :

```
(?<=[\s,*])[A-Za-z]\w*(?=[\s,*=;])
```

The Data :

```
keyword1 Apple
keyword2    Beer=0
keyword1     China,    Dime, Egg,    Fly, Google,   Koala, Lime
```

The result :

```
Apple
keyword2 
Beer
keyword1
China
Dime
Egg
Fly
Google
Koala
Lime
```

The Result I expected is simply 
Apple Beet China Dime Egg Fly Google Koala Lime

The idea is : 
If I found one keyword1 or keyword2 then collect the 'next' words 
if the 'next' word is divided with comma (,) then collect each word in the comma.
but don't include the keywords in the result.

I've tried all day but at the end I realized I need help on this..

Regards,

Ferry

Comment: You commented A can be Apple, B can be beer etc. So what is the difference between `Apple and unwantedword` or `beer and theunwantedwords`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion(I will fix the question), unwantedword will be at the begining of the line, it actually needed the rules is : if I found the unwanted words then find the 'next' word after the unwanted words if the 'next' words is divided by comma (,) then capture each word in the comma.

Comment: There are many dialects for Regex, each may have own special escape sequences: posix regex, perl regex, python regex, emacs regex... so which dialect do you use? (Although they share all some principels like character classes)

Comment: Hi math, you were right.. I learn those regex using .Net dialects and unfortunately I'm using it for Qt which is i realize (a moment ago) it's difference. now I'm trying to find the correct sequences for (?<=X) .. my mistakes not to learn the diffrence first.

Comment: Little software tip: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm - Expresso, a little tool to quickly write and test regex. You also can change the regex dialect there. Afaik QT uses the C++ dialect!? Not sure though, but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude the "keyword" you can do it like this:

```
(?!keyword)(?<=[\s,*])[A-Za-z]\w*(?=[\s,*=;])
```

Result:
Apple
Beer
China
Dime
Egg
Fly
Google
Koala